# Is there a docker image for wildfly 26.1.2 Final with JDK 8 support?

Tags: docker, java-8, wildfly

Is there a docker image for wildfly 26.1.2 Final with JDK 8 support ?

Answer (score 4):

WildFly images are moved from dockerhub and now available on Quay only. Images available on Docker Hub are not maintained anymore. No new builds of the WildFly image will be made available on Docker Hub. However you can use other providers docker images(eg: bitnami).

WildFly publishes images to run the application server with different JDK versions and all the available version can be seen [here](https://quay.io/repository/wildfly/wildfly?tab=tags&tag=jdk).

You can see there is no image with JDK 8 support. However, it is possible to create your own Docker image using a base image of WildFly and installing JDK 8 on top of it.

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:26.1.2.Final

USER root

RUN yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: I got "docker.io/jboss/wildfly:26.1.2.Final: not found" errors. Is this image still alive?